# Access Samba Share using Active Directory (LDAP)

Tags: networking, server, permissions, samba, ldap

I have Samba installed in our server and it is running fine. We have hundreds of folders in Samba share, and we use user.map to map list of users to specific folder in smb.share file. Since users are increasing to above hundreds, it is difficult to maintain such large number of users. Is it possible to use LDAP group to give access to samba share in specific folder?

For examples now we have foldera and folderb in our samba share. User1-user5 have access to foldera, and folderb for user6-user10. Now we have 400 users in foldera, and it keep increasing. How can we manage the access without updating the user.map everytime new user need access? Can it be done using LDAP group?

This is our current configuration:

smb.conf

```
[global]
    workgroup = AUTH
    security = ADS
    realm = AUTH.xxxxxxx.NET
    domain master = no
    os level = 10
    client lanman auth    = no
    client ntlmv2 auth    = yes
    client plaintext auth = no
    client schannel       = auto
    client signing        = auto
    client use spnego     = yes
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    pid directory    = /var/run/samba
    lock directory   = /var/run/samba
    private dir      = /var/log/samba/private
    username map     = /etc/samba/users.map
    include          = /etc/samba/smb.share
```

smb.share

```
[foldera]
  comment = Home Directories
  path = /opt/foldera
  valid users = usera
  public = no
  browseable = no
  writable = yes
  write list = usera

[folderb]
  comment = Home Directories
  path = /opt/folderb
  valid users = userb
  public = no
  browseable = no
  writable = yes
  write list = userb
```

users.map

```
usera= auth\user1
usera= auth\user2
usera= auth\user3
usera= auth\user4
usera= auth\user5
userb= auth\user6
userb= auth\user7
userb= auth\user8
userb= auth\user9
userb= auth\user10
```